# While Zipping files suing batch script it Zips the folder structure as well

Tags: batch-file, zip

I have files at location D:\data\Generate which needs to be Zipped and copied to

D:\data\Upload directory

I used command

set generate=D:\Data\Generate

set upload=D:\Data\Upload

cd %generate%

zip - * >> %upload%\%%i.zip

If I run this command from cmd it works fine but while running it from a 
scheduler (ex: Control-M) it actually copies all the files from Control-m config directory into the zip folder.

If I explicitly mention the directory under whose the files needs to be zipped

zip - %generate%*.* >> %upload%\%%i.zip

the final zip folder actually contains the whole directory structure too instead of just the files.

ex: Zip file contains Data folder, Generate folder and the files under Generate folder

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

ok I got some clue with this.

This is a problem with Windows itself, for ex:

You open CMD

You are currently in directory C

then you run a command cd D:\data

even after this when you do dir, it will list out all the jobs in C directory only.

if you run D: after the above CD it will actually go into D:\data directory and you can work on that directory

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are past this since two (2) years ago. Here is a way to do it. I did not understand what you wanted the .zip archive filename to be. There is nothing in the source code presented that would produce `%%i`.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'D:\Data\Generate' | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath 'D:\data\Upload\i.zip'"
```